# Can you help me identify these cookies?

Tags: cookies, food-identification

Can you help me identify all the cookies in this picture?
[image: 12 cookies]
General name is fine, like 2 is Gingerbread. Sorry if it is unclear from the picture, but this is all the info I have.

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't homework (if so, I might be willing to go back to class)... so some sort of treasure hunt or puzzle contest?

Comment: Google image search didn't find this image - where did it come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on Max's answer and provide missing items/detail:

1. Oatmeal raisin cookies
2. Gingerbread cookies
3. Milano cookies ([Pepperidge Farm](http://www.pepperidgefarm.com/productdetail.aspx?catid=725))
4. Peanut butter cookies
5. Macarons
6. Snowballs (or Mexican wedding cookies, or German pfeffernüsse, or Russian Tea Cakes...)
7. Chinese fortune cookie (Actually an [American bastardization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_cookie) of a Japanese cookie)
8. either Chinese almond cookie or oatmeal almond cookie
9. Sugar cookies
10. Chocolate mint cookies (similar to Girl Scout [Thin Mints](http://www.girlscouts.org/program/gs_cookies/meet_the_cookies.asp#mtc_thinmint) or Keebler [Grasshoppers](http://www.keebler.com/productdetail.aspx?category=cookies&pid=KIC-1124@EN_US))
11. Chocolate chip cookies
12. Biscotti

Comment: snowballs or Mexican wedding cookies?

Comment: It could honestly be either, but I'd have to see the inside. Snowballs are usually a little rounder than that picture now that I think about it, so go with the Mexican wedding cookies.

Comment: @Jolenealaska you're right! Edited

Comment: 6 is really not conclusive from the picture. Russian tea cakes can look like that too, if rolled in enough sugar.

Comment: @rumtscho True, but we can only infer so much from a picture.

Comment: 5 is a "French Macaroon" either lemon or lime, chocolate, vanilla and strawberry.  Also 6 is either a Mexican Wedding Cookie or Russian Tea Cake. Technically they are both called 
"Snowballs" in the US.  It depends on how small the nut is chopped, whether pecan or walnut is used, and how the ball is rolled and if the ball is rolled after it is cooked, once or twice.  Also, the bigger the ball, the flatter the botton because it is heavier cookie.

Answer (score 2):

1- raisin cookies
2- ginger bread cookies
3-
4- peanut butter cookies
5- macarons
6-
7- fortune cookies
8- chinese almond cookies
9- birthday/Christmas cookies :-)
10-
11- chocolate chips cookies
12- biscotti